# Convert data.frame to list of lists

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to figure out how to convert a data.frame to a list of lists. Suppose I had (feel free to modify this if you need to capture more attributes for later):

```
v <- list(
          row1=list(col1 = as.Date("2011-01-23"), col2="A"), 
          row2=list(col1 = as.Date("2012-03-03"), col2="B"))
d <- do.call(rbind, lapply(v, as.data.frame))
d$col3 <- 2
```

How do I get `d` back to a list of lists (similar to `v`). The end result should be equivalent to the result of:

```
vr <- list(
          row1=list(col1 = as.Date("2011-01-23"), col2="A", col3=2), 
          row2=list(col1 = as.Date("2012-03-03"), col2="B", col3=2))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
out <- lapply(split(d, rownames(d)), as.list)
out
#$row1
#$row1$col1
#[1] "2011-01-23"

#$row1$col2
#[1] "A"

#$row1$col3
#[1] 2


#$row2
#$row2$col1
#[1] "2012-03-03"

#$row2$col2
#[1] "B"

#$row2$col3
#[1] 2
```

If you add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when creating `d`, i.e.

```
d <- do.call(rbind, lapply(v, as.data.frame, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
d$col3 <- 2
```

then

```
identical(out, vr)
```

returns `TRUE`.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You have to go through the columns again making them lists before you pass them as values of the element of the main list. I hope the below code helps:

```
apply(d,MARGIN = 1, FUN=function(x){as.list(x)})
```

Comment: Yeah, It can also be simplified this way.

Comment: You would need to be careful though because all elements end up being coerced to characters when you use `apply`.